# Can I add sub folders to a SQL Server Management Studio Project?

Tags: sql-server-2005

What is the best way to keep large projects organized with SSMS?

I want to do something like:

```
ProjectRoot
    SchemaObjects
        Tables
            Constraints
            Indexes
            Keys
        Functions
        Views
        Stored Procedures
     Scripts
         DataGeneration
```

And so on, but I cannot find a nice way to do this... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's anyway way to do this in SMSS, at least not in 2005.
Maybe a third party tool will give you this; there's a list of replacements for 2000 Enterprise Manager [here](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-manage-sql-server/msde.html); not the most current, but probably a good starting point.

Comment: Not in 2008 either, unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 3):

Sadly there isn't.  Maintain your object scripts out side of SSMS and simply edit them in SSMS.

IMHO this is one thing that is lacking big time in SSMS.